# greenlife.no is loading ie instances that redirect to anti-virus software (koobface)

Tags: virus

A friend was using my computer and attempted to download flash from an unknown website and inadvertantly infected my computer with a virus. From time to time a new tab opens in IE with a url beginning with greenlife.no that then redirects to a site selling anti-virus software. Has anybody seen this particular virus before? The link was on facebook by the way.

it turns out that this is koobface. is there a recommended program to remove koobface (major facebook worm)

Answer (score 1):

The [facebook support page](http://www.facebook.com/security) refers a lot of on-line Virus Scanners.
And, [Kaspersky](http://www.kaspersky.com/virusscanner) is a good scanner.
Also, [How to Remove Koobface.B Worm Manually](http://www.411-spyware.com/koobface-b-worm#deletefiles) and the [eHow reference](http://www.ehow.com/how_4664729_remove-koobface-facebook-virus.html).

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this before and it gets really annoying.. This is a type of spam bot trying to get you to download useless anti virus software. Run your anti virus software and if you have anything that can scan for spam do that also.

Comment: it turns out that this is koobface, thanks for the help